# Got NoSuchElementException even though this element exists

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Dear Selenium Webdriver Specialists,

I am getting the following exception (on the if statement) when carrying out XPath query on 
"/html/body/form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a" from http://www.domain.com.au/Property/For-Sale/House/NSW/Auburn/?adid=2010111460:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a"}
```

Below is the code snippet where this exception has taken place:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.domain.com.au/Property/For-Sale/House/NSW/Auburn/?adid=2010111460");

if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a")).isDisplayed() && 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a")).getAttribute("href").length() > 0) {
    WebElement photoPageElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a"));
    photoPageURL = photoPageElement.getAttribute("href");
    .....
}
```

This code snippets have been successful with locating same element from other property such as http://www.domain.com.au/Property/For-Sale/House/NSW/Auburn/?adid=2010007127.

I am looking for a good quality XML/XHTML explorer to traverse the same document in order to identify the cause of such exception.

Is it possible to check the existence of an element without the risk of getting an exception? I thought the driver.findElement(By.xpath(....).isDisplayed()) was meant to do that.

I am running Selenium Webdriver 2.25.0, Java 7.0, Netbeans 7.2 on Windows XP / 7.

Your advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Comment: That XPath query is destined for failure. You do not need to go all the way down the tree, starting from `html` and to your element. Also what's with the references to the exact position of the DIV's? If I add in an extra div before the this one: `/form/div[2]/`, it's going to break. Also...running your XPath query on that site, for me at least, returns no results at all. Can you point on what element you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend for you to start using CSS and id locators instead of XPath to make your scripts more readable and robust. CSS locators should also be faster, which comes in handy when running a bigger suite of tests. For figuring out element locators there's plenty of options: without installing anything there's right-click -> Inspect element in Chrome and Firefox, and Developer Tools in IE for example.

There's probably some issue with your XPath locator, which results in the NoSuchElementException. If you're expecting this, you could catch the exception, but if the point is to get the link URL you probably don't want to do that.

For example, looking at the page you linked first, the big picture is wrapped inside an a-element:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_propertyPhotos_MainImage_MainPhotoLink" class="feature" target="ImageWindow" href="/ore/Public/Gallery/Photo.aspx?adid=2010111460&pic=1&mode=Buy">
```

Locating this element with id with WebDriver in Java:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_propertyPhotos_MainImage_MainPhotoLink"));
```

And then reading the href:

```
String linkHref = element.getAttribute("href");
```

You can read about CSS selectors [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), with them you can do things such as click the `<img>` inside the MainImage `<div>` in WebDriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_propertyPhotos_MainImage_upnlHeroImage img")).click();
```

Comment: Failed due to "&" after pic=1 from http://www.domain.com.au/ore/Public/Gallery/Photo.aspx?adid=2010111460&amp;pic=1&amp;mode=Buy. How to get successful XPath when encountering "&" after pic=1?

Comment: There are many properties found in [link]http://www.domain.com.au/Search/buy/Property/Types/Duplex/House/New-Home-Designs/New-House-Land/Penthouse/Semi-Detached/Terrace/Townhouse/Villa/State/NSW/Area/Parramatta/Region/Sydney-Region/Suburb/Auburn/?bedrooms=1%2c2%2c3&carspaces=1&from=500000&searchterm=2144[/link] where the More Details button / URL will take us into the detail of each property.

Comment: The problem with searching for this element based on ID which changes from time to time (not unique):
class=”lnkMainImage”
ID: ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_premierPlusListing_premierGallery_linkImagePanel
/ore/Public/Gallery/Photo.aspx?adid=2010122681&pic=1

class=”lnkMainImage”
ID: ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_propertyPhotos_MainImage_MainPhotoLink
/ore/Public/Gallery/Photo.aspx?adid=2010137600&pic=1&mode=Buy”
Looks like we should use selector driver.findElement(By.XPath(“class=’ lnkMainImage’”). getAttribute("href"), whether using By.XPath / By.cssSelector will find the right element.

Comment: Btw, my intention is not to lookup these images from this page but to go to the MainImage page in attribute “href”, to download each image one by one using general Java I/O class.

Comment: Also, can driver.findElement(By.cssSelector….) prevent exception from occurring if the element doesn’t exist? Using driver.findElement(By.XPath Selector….).isDisplay() has failed to achieve this objective.

Comment: Excellent advice on useful element locators in Firefox & IE. I found Developer Tools in IE is very user friendly. Thank you.

Comment: @Matti are you implying that xpath is less robust of a search function than using find by CSS? Can you explain why?

Comment: @franklin I guess I was, but maybe more based on personal experience on typical XPath locator usage, than the actual robustness of the search function. For me it seemed that more of the people using XPath were using long, absolute locators, which will give a false positive in a test script whenever a front-end dev introduces an unexpected <div> in the hierarchy, for instance. Using smaller, relative and descriptive locators don't do this so often, needing less test maintenance work, but now looking at XPath syntax more closely, technically this can be achieved with XPath too.

Comment: That's a a sort of "meta-programming" problem though. If you know what I mean. It stems from I think two things. First, the inability of some programmers to ask: How can good code be made better to the point where it's logic can be recycled anywhere? But it's also external pressure to produce something that "works" rather than produce something that's workable.