# Selenium WebDriver throws NoSuchElementException even though the element exists (verified with Firebug/FirePath)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, nosuchelementexception

I use this code in Selenium WebDriver to extract the value of a certain element on a non-Ajax web page.

```
    public int getNumberOfPages(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            webDriverBackedSelenium.click(linkLastPage);
1               webDriverBackedSelenium.waitForPageToLoad(normalTimeout);
2               new WebDriverWait(driver, normalTimeoutS).until(ExpectedConditions
                        .presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(linkFirstPage)));
3               return Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath(pathToNumberOfPages))
                        .getText());            
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                webDriverBackedSelenium.click(linkPreviousPage);
                webDriverBackedSelenium.waitForPageToLoad(normalTimeout);
            } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
4               return Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath(pathToNumberOfPages))
                        .getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

If I have a breakpoint at (1), open Firebug and insert the XPath the element is found but when I run this I get a NoSuchElementException at both 3 and 4 (if I set breakpoints there, again using FirePath, the element is found as expected).

I tried different kinds if waits, e.g., 1 and 2 above, one at a time as well as both simultaneously, always with the same result.

The timeouts are set to 30 seconds/30 000 milliseconds.

I have read two similar questions

- [webdriver findElement throws NoSuchElementException even though its inside try/catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449483/webdriver-findelement-throws-nosuchelementexception-even-though-its-inside-try-c)
- [Got NoSuchElementException even though this element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606134/got-nosuchelementexception-even-though-this-element-exists)

but the answers there does not apply to my situation (since I have verified that the element is there with FirePath).

The bl**dy element is there so why doesn't Selenium find it?

**XPath**

```
//tr[@class='rgPager']//a[@class='PagerItem'] [@title='Första']
```

**HTML**

```
<a title="Första" class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl04','')" style="display:inline;">&lt;&lt;</a>&nbsp;<a title="Föregående" class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl05','')" style="display:inline;">&lt;</a>&nbsp;<a class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl06','')" style="display:inline;">...</a>&nbsp;<a class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl07','')">161</a>&nbsp;<a class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl08','')">162</a>&nbsp;<a class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl09','')" style="display:none;">...</a>&nbsp;<a title="Nästa" class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl10','')" style="display:none;">&gt;</a>&nbsp;<a title="Sista" class="PagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl11','')" style="display:none;">&gt;&gt;</a>&nbsp;<br><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl12','')">A</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl13','')">B</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl14','')">C</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl15','')">D</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl16','')">E</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl17','')">F</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl18','')">G</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl19','')">H</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl20','')">I</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl21','')">J</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl22','')">K</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl23','')">L</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl24','')">M</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl25','')">N</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl26','')">O</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl27','')">P</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl28','')">Q</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl29','')">R</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl30','')">S</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl31','')">T</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl32','')">U</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl33','')">V</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl34','')">W</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl35','')">X</a>&nbsp;Y&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl36','')">Z</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl37','')">Å</a>&nbsp;Ä&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl38','')">Ö</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="SelectedPagerItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01$cphContent$Quickrank1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl39','')">Alla</a>
```

Comment: Can you please post the snippet of HTML (with parent elements if possible) that you are trying to find and the respective XPath expression used in the findElement method.

Comment: Paste your xpath and html

Comment: XPath: //tr[@class='rgPager']//a[@class='PagerItem'] [@title='Första']

Comment: Are there frame elements on the page? Are you able to find that rgPager tr? Is `a` the child of that tr?

Comment: No frames. Yes I can find an element for //tr[@class='rgPager']. There is a td without class/id between the tr and the a. The whole xpath works fine when I use it manually in Firebug.

Comment: What does `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@class='rgPager']")` give you? Is there more than one? You might also want to try `driver.getPageSource()` and check that the driver has loaded the right page html.